# Manipulate onmouseover properties, not my own site

Tags: jquery, image, replace, popup, onmouseover

There's a site that I use frequently that has a list of links, when you hover over one of them a small pop-up image is displayed. I would like to make these images bigger, that's it. The site is using the overLIB library to generate the pop-ups, which isn't important though.

To do that you could simply change part of the img URL, which is the part I need help with.

A link could look something like this:

```
<a title="" href=" link-url " onmouseout="return nd();"
onmouseover="return overlib('<img src=\'http://dyncdn.me/static/over/blabla.jpg\'
border=0>')"> link-text </a>
```

What I need to do is, with JavaScript/jQuery via Greasemonkey, to change the "static/over/" part of the img-src-url to "static/over/" because then it would link to a bigger image that's on the site.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.onmouseover = this.onmouseover.replace('static/over/', 'posters2/d/');
    });
});
```

which will work for "href", "title" and so on but not for the "onmouseover".
Se this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/demondriver/93ut3/) for an example where part of the "href" is replaced.

Since I'm a novice at JavaScript I don't even know if this is possible.

Comment: @Zenith using Greasemonkey addon.

Comment: @roasted Ahh I see that now :)